# Count number of decimal places in a Float (or Decimal) in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to count the number of decimal places (ignoring trailing zeros) in a Float (or NSDecimalNumber) for example:

```
1.45000 => 2
5.98 => 2
1.00 => 0
0.857 => 3
5 => 0
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: That does not make much sense with binary floating point numbers because they cannot represent all values precisely. For example, with `let x = 1.45` the variable `x` actually holds the value `1.4499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Doing this with Decimal is fairly straightforward, provided you correctly create your Decimal. Decimals are stored as `significand * 10^exponent`. `significand` is normalized to the smallest integer possible. So for 1230, the significand is 123 and the exponent is 1. For 1.23 the significand is also 123 and the exponent is -2. That leads us to:

```
extension Decimal {
    var significantFractionalDecimalDigits: Int {
        return max(-exponent, 0)
    }
}
```

However, you must be very careful constructing your Decimal. If you construct it from a Double, you will already have applied binary rounding errors. So for example:

```
let n = Decimal(0.111) // 0.11100000000000002048 because you passed a Double
n.significantFractionalDecimalDigits // 20
```

vs.

```
let n = Decimal(string: "0.111")!
n.significantFractionalDecimalDigits // 3 what you meant
```

Keep in mind of course that Decimal has a maximum number of significant digits, so it may still apply rounding.

```
let n = Decimal(string: "12345678901235678901234567890.1234567890123456789")!
n.significantFractionalDecimalDigits // 9 ("should" be 19)
```

And if you're walking down this road at all, you really must read the [Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and the canonical StackOverflow question: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 12):

For me, there is quite easy solution that works on any region and device because iOS will handle possible binary errors for you automatically:

```
extension Double {
    func decimalCount() -> Int {
        if self == Double(Int(self)) {
            return 0
        }

        let integerString = String(Int(self))
        let doubleString = String(Double(self))
        let decimalCount = doubleString.count - integerString.count - 1

        return decimalCount
    }
}
```

Edit: it should work same for Double or Float

Comment: Great answer. This may fail though if `String(Double(self))` prints the number using scientific notation (e.g.: "1.2e-6"). To make sure one gets Double as decimal value only, use `"\(NSNumber(value: Double(self)).decimalValue)"`.

Answer (score 3):

This is terrible , but you can actually **count the length of the string after the dot**.

```
extension Double {
    
    var decimalPlaces: Int {
        let decimals = String(self).split(separator: ".")[1]
        return decimals == "0" ? 0 : decimals.count
    }
}
```

```
print(3.decimalPlaces) // 0
print(3.1.decimalPlaces) // 1
print(3.14.decimalPlaces) // 2
print(3.1415.decimalPlaces) // 4
print(3.141592.decimalPlaces) // 6
print(3.14159265.decimalPlaces) // 8
```

Comment: This is not safe method, because number can be formatted to "3.14" or "3,14", depending of region of device.

Comment: @IvoLeko **Actually I don't disagree at all.**  I would not use it in production either, yet it did the job nicely for some counting tasks in an internal/prototype project. I like how it leverages the decimal calculation thing implemented in the `String` type itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually *really hard* due to floating point not being representable precisely in a decimal format. For example the nearest 64 bit IEEE754 floating point to 5.98 is

`5.980000000000000426325641456060111522674560546875`

Presumably in this case you want the answer to be 2.

The easiest thing to do is to use your favourite converter to a string, formatted to 15 significant figures (for a double precision type) and inspect the output. It's not particularly fast, but it will be reliable. For a 32 bit floating point type, use 7 significant figures.

That said, if you can use a decimal type from the get-go then do that.

Comment: I like the idea of decimal type, I can change the data type. But how do I count the precision on NSDecimalNumber then?

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach? According to [Here](https://numerics.diploid.ca/numeric-protocols.html) both Float and Double are BinaryFloatingPoint. So:

```
public extension Numeric where Self: BinaryFloatingPoint {

    /// Returns the number of decimals. It will be always greater than 0
    var numberOfDecimals: Int {
        let integerString = String(Int(self))
        //Avoid conversion issue
        let stringNumber: String
        if self is Double {
            stringNumber = String(Double(self))
        }
        else {
            stringNumber = String(Float(self))
        }
        let decimalCount = stringNumber.count - integerString.count - 1

        return decimalCount
    }
    
}
```